# How to assert that method is not run concurrently (or fail-fast when it is)?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

Is there a way to fail-fast as soon as multiple threads enter a method which is known *not* to be thread-safe?

Edit: Assuming a method is synchronized externally and not supposed to run concurrently. However, if external synchronization fails for some reason, it would be great to fail as soon as possible, thus avoiding subtle race-condition issues. Also, since the method normally runs in a single thread only, would be great to avoid/minimize synchronization penalty of the check.

Comment: Known by who? And known how?

Comment: That's going to be difficult without introducing some sort of synchronization...

Comment: Please clarify your question so that we know what your problem is.  Try providing an example of what you have tried, and the errors or problems you are having with your solution.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Sometimes you just know ;)

Comment: _You_ do, but how does the program know? Do you own the source code? Can you just make the method thread safe? Can you work around it? Make thread local instances of the class the method belongs to.

Comment: How a method can fail fast if the current implementation is not failing fast? Either you alter the implementation or the caller thread use a wrapper method.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I've added some explanation to the question. The intention is not to make method thread-safe, but to fail as soon as external synchronization fails.

Comment: If DI was used with interfaces, it'd be "easy" to proxy/wrap the problematic operation ;-)

Comment: I stand behind my close vote.  It is difficult to understand the problem that OP is trying to solve.  If the code is synchronized externally, then it will not fail and there does not need to be a check.  If the code is not synchronized externally, then full synchronization needs to be done internally if thread-safe behavior is required.

Comment: @ErickRobertson Just trying to ensure that module is used properly and fail if it's not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lock solutions, here, all add performance overhead, and I'm guessing you didn't make the class thread-safe for that reason. Java's collections are in the same situation, and they solved it with a "mod count" field in the class. It's not perfect (AtomicInteger would be better), and it's not guaranteed, but it catches *most* cases.

```
public class Foo {
    private volatile int modCount = 0;
    public void threadUnsafeMethod() {
        int startModCount = ++modCount;
        ...
        if (modCount != startModCount) { throw new ConcurrentModificationException(); }
    }
}
```

If you just want to guard, you could do

```
public class Foo {
    private final AtomicBoolean inThreadUnsafeMethod = new AtomicBoolean();
    public void threadUnsafeMethod() {
        if (!inThreadUnsafeMethod.compareAndSet(false, true) {
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        }
        try {
            ...
        } finally {
            inThreadUnsafeMethod.set(false);
        }
    }
}
```

With both, be *very* careful with handle reentrant calls correctly. `this.otherThreadUnsafeMethod();` shouldn't fail.

Take a look at the `ArrayList` [implementation](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/ArrayList.java.html) (search for `modCount`).

Comment: Use `AtomicInteger`. `++` is not atomic.

Comment: I mentioned that in my post. *"It's not perfect (AtomicInteger would be better)"*

Comment: Not only is it not _perfect_, it's wrong. You can correct it by modifying your code snippet to use `AtomicInteger`.

Comment: It's the approach `ArrayList` uses to catch *most* concurrent modifications with minimal overhead. If you absolutely need to be certain, you should switch to locking because you might have a collision when the AtomicInteger overflows.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The fact that this implementation is not guaranteed to always throw the exception, on any platform, when there is an overlapped call does not make it "wrong".  It's a compromise.  It somewhat improves the chance of catching a mis-use of the function.  It's not as reliable as using AtomicInteger for the same purpose, but it also does not cost as much.  Atomics are a form of synchronization too.

Comment: @jameslarge Maybe I'm making too many assumptions, but it seems to me like OP wants to catch all cases.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The answer is quite clear that there is a "light" option that works on a best effort basis and a "heavier" option that always works. I think it gives good alternatives for whatever the OP is trying to achieve (which is vague).

Comment: @assylias Yeah, looks like several approaches are possible. In any case it's helpful to know what are the options.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann Funny enough, the `modCount` or `atomicBoolean` approaches fail when same thread enters the designated method(s) more than once. This can be easily handled, though.

Comment: @IvanBalashov That's what I meant by "reentrant calls," and it's something ReentrantLocks handle very gracefully.

Answer (score 3):

I use an `AtomicBoolean`. First we have:

```
private final AtomicBoolean isExecuting = new AtomicBoolean();
```

Then, first thing we do in method not supposed to be executed concurrently:

```
if (isExecuting.getAndSet(true)) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

Make sure that the one thread executing your method reset the flag on exit:

```
try {
    // ... method implementation
}
finally {
    isExecuting.set(false);
}
```

You may see two real world examples [here](https://github.com/MartinanderssonDotcom/java-ee-concepts/blob/master/src/test/java/com/martinandersson/javaee/cdi/scope/application/ConcurrentInvocationCounter.java#L39-L42) and [here](https://github.com/MartinanderssonDotcom/java-ee-concepts/blob/master/src/test/java/com/martinandersson/javaee/ejb/sessionbeans/AbstractSessionBean.java#L111-L113).

Comment: Can't think why this was -1'd apart from the fact that the OP asked how to do it without introducing any new synchronization, and Atomics _are_ a form of synchronization.  Still doesn't deserve the -1 though:  It works, and doing _exactly_ what the OP wanted is not possible.

Comment: This is quite similar to the modcount approach mentioned here. Indeed, this is one of the choices I was initially hoping to get. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could create a lock and a wrapper method and then you can make each caller to invoke this method

```
private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
public void wrapperMethod() {
    if (!lock.tryLock())
        throw new RuntimeException()
    try {
        threadUnsafeMethod();
    }
    finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

With `tryLock` the caller tries to acquire the lock immediately. If the lock is already been acquired by some other caller it returns `false` and we throw an exception.

If you want to make **each** caller to fail fast in case of concurrent invocations, then it means that no two threads access the method concurrently. Otherwise, one of the two threads must have failed. This way you **effectively** add thread safety to your method.

An equivalent method using atomic longs but that remains a locking mechanism:

```
AtomicLong threadId = new AtomicLong(-1);
public void wrapperMethod() {
    threadId.compareAndSet(-1, Thread.currentThread().getId());
    if (threadId.get() != Thread.currentThread().getId())
        throw new RuntimeException();
    try {
        threadUnsafeMethod();
    }
    finally {
        threadId.set(-1);
    }
}
```

Saying that, if you allow to use only a specific thread to run the code, this gives the idea for threads to run a contest. Then use only the winner for running the method:

```
AtomicLong winningThreadId = new AtomicLong(-1);

public void runContest() {
    winningThreadId.compareAndSet(-1, Thread.currentThread().getId());
}

public void wrapperMethod() {
    if (winningThreadId.get() != Thread.currentThread().getId())
        throw new RuntimeException();
    threadUnsafeMethod();
}
```

So every candidate thread runs the contest once and afterwards it uses the wrapper method.

Comment: A call to `tryLock` must be balanced with a call to `unlock`.

Comment: If you add this, then the method becomes thread safe. I would assume the OP cannot do this.